# How can i find mysql table column name by using matching value in same table column data?

Tags: mysql

How can i find mysql table column name by using  matching string value in same table column data ?

My table:
Table name:namelist

---

| First_name | Last_name |
| --- | --- |
| Stack | overflow |
| overflow | Stack |

Expecting Output

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM namelist LIKE 'Stack';
```

---

| First_name |
| --- |
| Last_name |

I need Column name by using search string value in same table.

Comment: You want a column name using a value inside it? Not sure I understood

Answer (score 0):

You seem to have a non standard requirement, but here is one approach using `CONCAT_WS` with `CASE` expressions:

```sql
SELECT CONCAT_WS(',',
           CASE WHEN SUM(First_name = 'Stack') > 0 THEN 'First_name' END,
           CASE WHEN SUM(Last_name = 'Stack') > 0  THEN 'Last_name' END
       ) AS matching_columns
FROM yourTable;
```